# How to boot to command prompt with network

Tags: 11.10, boot

I have an Ubuntu 11.10 machine and would like it to boot to command prompt with network. I've read some solutions but they are all for previous versions and some disable also the network, which is not what i want.

Is it possible?

Comment: please add the links to the solutions you have tried so that you dont get the same answers...

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to do. For example, the fastest way I know is to boot using "recovery mode" and choosing "netroot": http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/401/recoverymode.png/

The bad side is that you login as root... with all the security consequences that follow. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only wanting to boot into a a Command Promt. (In Linux it is usually refereed to the as the shell) you can move from your Graphical session to a shell by pressing `ctrl + alt + and function key from one to six.` (function key if your on a laptop maybe) This will take you to a log in page at the shell. Now if you need to do anything from here with the shell here you can. You can also just open a terminal if you need most likely. Now press `ctrl + alt + f7` to go back to the GUI.